# Is it possible to upload an image to SharePoint using the Graph API in C# by passing through base64?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, restsharp

I am trying to upload an image (.png/.bmp) to SharePoint using the Graph API within C#. I can do this successfully in Postman using the following (the image uploads and appears correctly):
[image]

I've tried using the postman generated C# RestSharp call, and some spin offs of this but no luck. It will create the .png file within SharePoint and return a success but I get the following:
[image]

In the bottom right of the Postman call, you can see "file contents here", I'm honestly not sure what value this is looking for in terms of an image. Is there a way to pass through the base64 value here? I've tried passing the parameter as image/png, application/json, I've tried adding a Content Type header. I've tried passing various values through but I'm completely stumped. This is the basics of the code sample:

```
        var ret = new Result();

        var client = new RestClient(path);
        var request = new RestRequest();
        request.Method = verb;
        
        request.AddParameter("text/plain", base64, ParameterType.RequestBody);
       
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {bearerToken}");
        
        var requestResults = client.Execute(request);
        ret.Data = requestResults.Content;
        return ret;
```

I've been using this Microsoft doc for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

Let me know if this is possible and where I'm going wrong, thanks!

Comment: RestSharp sends a multipart form (MIME),  See https://restsharp.dev/usage?force_isolation=true#get-or-post and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true  A Mime is in the body of the message and first line of each part starts with two dashes.

Comment: @jdweng I get the same result running the calls from your link, for example:
// Adds an array of bytes
AddFile(parameterName, bytes, fileName, contentType);

Comment: Is add file adding a multipart?   A multipart has to look like sample.  Your link is is not MIME.  It is just adding data to the body of a request.  See : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/e16ad39b-790e-449d-8740-c48776dd72d1/upload-file-in-rest-api-with-multipart-form-data?forum=aspdotnetcore&force_isolation=true

Comment: Not sure, I tried adding a multipart off some articles though. What's even more interesting in my opinion is if I post just a text file, it has all of the base64 characters and I can copy that to a converter and it appears perfectly. Why isn't SharePoint reading it though :(

Comment: When you post text is it a multipart?  Sharepoint is probably expecting only image type an not text.  The multipart has a type and type is wrong.  I usually use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare good with bad.  Use HTTP (not HTTPS) to see the request unencrypted. It will not connect but you can see request in sniffer for comparison.

Comment: Nope! It just has the base64 value -- Maybe they don't accept base64? I'll check out fiddler

Comment: Look at the yellow image above which is the successful Graph APi.  There are 6 items.  Some are http headers.  The last is the type in the MIME.  The type in MIME is TEXT.  Images are binary, not text.  Which means it used a Base64 string.  GZIP would be labeled Accept-Encoding: gzip;

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Had to convert from base64 to binary:

```
    Convert.FromBase64String(base64Image);
```

And then in the RestSharp call:

```
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    request.AddHeader("Content-Length", binaryImage.Length);
    request.AddParameter("application/octet-stream", binaryImage, 
    ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

And just don't include any other headers/parameters to avoid the multipart request